# Show entire object in template

Tags: javascript, angular

Using Angular 5, I am trying to show all properties of an object.

With a collection of objects such as:

```
testobjects = [
    {"customer": "Me", "ID": "1"},
    {"customer": "You", "ID": "2"},
    {"customer": "Him", "ID": "3"},
    {"customer": "Her", "ID": "4"}
];
```

and with HTML:

```
  <div *ngFor="let testobject of testobjects">
    <span>{{testobject}}</span>
    <span>{{testobject.customer}}</span>
  </div>
```

I can get `testobject.customer` in the template but not `testobject`.

How can I show the entire object?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(yourObject)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [JSON Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe).

```
<div *ngFor="let testobject of testobjects">
<span>{{testobject | json}}</span>
<span>{{testobject.customer}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angulars json pipe

`<div> {{testobject | json }}</div>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `{{testobject | json }}`

Answer (score 0):

You can also well format it using the pre tag:

```
<pre>{{testobject | json }}</pre>
```